# how to assign a hash key to a string variable

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to assign a Hash key value which comes after 512 hash key generation, I am unable to do the same that's why please suggest me the right solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some more explanation of your question?

Comment: There is no any large explanation of my question, Its simple as I want to assign a Hexadecimal hash key value to a string variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
// Somehow you retrieve the hash key.
long keyAsLong = getHashKey();

// And then you convert it to a hex string.
String keyAsString = Long.toHexString(keyAsLong);
```